# SQLAlchemy insert time to MySQL incorrectly

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I define a Column whose type is DateTime, Time, TIMESTAMP, whatever it always appeared such warning:

```
Warning: Incorrect time value: '2017-02-13 21:39:06.956895' for column 'time' at row 1
```

I have googled such warning for a long time so please do not explain to me why further.And after an insertion, such column value show like this:`21:39:07`, but what i want is : `2017-02-13 21:39:06`, so anybody can give me some easy and proper solution? thanks.

Here is a Column definition using DateTime :`time = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), default=datetime.datetime.utcnow())`

OS version:OS X 10.11.4
Python version: 3.5.2

Comment: share the column and date type of it.

Comment: Have you created the table from the SQLAlchemy model definition, or are you just "reflecting" an existing schema? It seems that the real datatype of the underlying SQL table is just "time", not datetime, and as such it cannot store the date part. You'll have to include the real DB table definition along with your SQLAlchemy model class for anyone to be able to answer this properly. I'll bet this is yet another case of MySQL just issuing warnings instead of refusing entirely to insert invalid data.

Comment: You are right, I remember setting the column type as `Time` and such exception happened and then changed it with `DateTime`, but after i checked mysql table column definition and find its data type was `time`, so whatever i define SQLAlchemy entity column type using `time` or `datetime` , it will not change mysql origin data type.

Answer (score 0):

It Accepts datetime.datetime object.
for example:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
```

will work with you.